# Unknown column "something" in `Field list`, What's wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I'm writing a server at port 3000 and its job is to get the data from "Signup.ejs" input's values and then inserting them into the database.

All is fine but there's a problem, it says to me that TechnoBoy is an unknown column in `Field list`

I tried inserting "" or even `` around ${} but it didn't work well since a new error has appeared.

This is my Connection.js file that I use it to create a connection and then export it to connect it in my app's files:

```
let mysql = require("mysql");
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "something",
  database: "test"
});

module.exports = connection;
```

And this is my Server.js that I use it to create a server and connect to the database insert the data into it:

```
let connection = require("./Connection.js");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("The server at port 3000 is open!");
});
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/Signup", (req, res) => {
  res.render("Register");
});
connection.connect();
app.post("/Signup", urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.render("Register");
  connection.query(
    `insert into users (Username, User_Password) values (${
      req.body.Username
    }, ${req.body.Password})`
  );
});
```

Error I receive when I insert some data into input fields:

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'TechnoBoy' in 'field list'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:200:25)
    at C:\Users\ha\OneDrive\Images\Documents\Projects\UI-Server\Server.js:17:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at C:\Users\ha\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:425:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Protocol._delegateError (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:390:10)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:153:12)
    at Query.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:78:12)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:90:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\ha\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
```

The query I used(which is in connection.query btw):

```
insert into users (Username, User_Password) values (${
          req.body.Username
        }, ${req.body.Password})
```

Excuse me if this is a stupid question or something, I'm very new to backend and this one is my first try on it.

Comment: Can you please provide the SQL query that has been causing this? I have a strange feeling that `TechnoBoy` is a value intended for `Username` column and you may encounter a SQL-injection or miss-handling of input data.

Comment: And I guess this is about #nodejs ? Then please remove #javascript tag and add #nodejs .

Comment: @Roland Oh I already wrote the query I used which is: insert into users (Username, User_Password) values (${
      req.body.Username
    }, ${req.body.Password}) Yeah, TechnoBoy is a value intended for Username column, I want it to record it in the column. What do you mean with miss-handling of input data? Excuse me sir, I'm very new to servers and databases thing.

Comment: @Roland I did the changes.

Comment: sorry for overseeing it. With "miss-handling" I mean not escaping data that comes from an untrusted source like the Internet is. So it is a general good advice to escape ("secure") your user's input data before it reaches any sensitive part like SQL queries where a potential attacker can insert malicious code like ` OR 1=1`.

Comment: The simple reason why I'm guessing this (no knowledge in NodeJS) is, what the error message states: `Unknown column TechnoBoy in field list`. This may mean you are missing single apostrophes in your SQL query. Because when you leave them out and the NodeJS code is not adding it "smartly" to it, the value `TechnoBoy` is being inserted into your SQL statement, resulting to `INSERT INTO users (Username, User_password) VALUES (TechnoBoy, abc123#)`. If you would use `'` around your values, `TechnoBoy` is then interpreted as value by the SQL engine and this is what you want here.

Comment: @Roland Oh you mean like XSS? Anyway, the problem got solved now. Thanks for the informations.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an idiot. I configured Password field to be int so it can't enter strings but I passed it a string, that's why when I was passing it, it was saying wrong syntax and stuff.

Oh and also, I forgot to wrap the username with "" although I still don't know how it is a problem when the property is a string itself.

Problem got solved, it can be closed now.